# Finding all rational canonical forms of a matrix in $M_{5}(\mathbb{Q})$ given it's minimum polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Given a $5\times 5$ matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, with minimum polynomial $p(x)=(x-2)(x^{2}+1)^{2}$, how do I find all possible rational canonical forms of A? How do I find how many similarity classes exist with the same minimum polynomial? How many Jordan canonical forms of A exist if instead we take the matrix to have entries in $\mathbb{C}$? And in that case, how many similarity classes exist?

Comment: Does this involve the FT of Finite Abelian Groups in any way? (Also if anybody has a link to a page that explains this process that would be helpful as a supplementary reference. I'd like a formal explanation though if possible)

Comment: It is part of a generalization of FTFAG. You may know that an abelian group is just a $\mathbb{Z}$ module, and $\mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal domain. The generalization is to any finitely generated module over a principal ideal domain. You can find this explained thoroughly in almost any algebra text, such as Dummit and Foote (mostly in chapter 12).

Comment: Is there a name for this generalized theorem?

Comment: Structure theorem?

Comment: Yes. Or fundamental theorem of finitely generated modules over a principal ideal domain.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a good tactic is to think about the possible [Smith Normal Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form), which are in bijection with similarity classes. The last polynomial in the bunch is the minimal polynomial, and the product of all the $\alpha_i$ is the characteristic polynomial.

In this case, the minimal polynomial $p(X)$is of degree $5$, which is the same degree as the characteristic polynomial, so there is only one possible Smith Normal Form, given by $1,1,1,1, p(x)$. So there is only one possible similarity class of matrices satisfying the condition you state (over $\mathbb{Q}$ or over $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

We are given that $A\in M_{5\times 5}(\Bbb Q)$ and that
\begin{align*}                                                                                 
\textstyle{\min_A}(t)                                                                                      
&= (t-2)\left(t^2+1\right)^2 \\                                                                
&= t^5-2\,t^4+2\,t^3-4\,t^2+t-2                                                                
\end{align*}
Since $\deg\min_A(t)=5$  it follows that
$\min_A(t)=\DeclareMathOperator{char}{char}\char_A(t)$.   Thus the rational
canonical form of $A$ is simply    the companion matrix of $\min_A(t)$
$$                                                                                             
\begin{bmatrix}                                                                                
0&0&0&0&2\\                                                                                    
1&0&0&0&-1 \\                                                                                  
0&1&0&0&4\\                                                                                    
0&0&1&0&-2\\                                                                                   
0&0&0&1&2                                                                                      
\end{bmatrix}                                                                                  
$$
To compute the possible Jordan forms $J$ of $A$, note that the eigenvalues of $A$ are
\begin{align*}
\lambda_1 &= 2 & \lambda_2 &= i & \lambda_3 &= -i
\end{align*}
and that the algebraic multiplicities of the eigenvalues are
\begin{align*}
\DeclareMathOperator{amult}{amult}\amult(\lambda_1)
 &=1 & 
\amult(\lambda_2) &= 2 &
\amult(\lambda_3) &= 2
\end{align*}
Since $\min_A(t)=\char_A(t)$ we know that the sizes of the largest Jordan block corresponding to $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, and $\lambda_3$ are $1$, $2$, and $2$ respectively. What does this say about $J$?

Comment: @EricAuld Whoops. Corrected.